# Make Docker machine very fast

Tags: docker, docker-machine, dinghy

I'm using **Docker** on **Mac** with the docker toolbox which use **Virtual box**.

I love docker and I think this is the future, but it's kind of slow using VM.

My question is: `Is there a way to accelerate the process with VM?`

I heard about dinghy: https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy, which use sharing with NFS. It sounds complicated to set up.
Do you think it is very useful to try it or there is another solution?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is "slow"? Processing power? File access? You may be interested in "Docker for Mac", which was announced last week, and solves a lot of issues that were caused by VirtualBox https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/

Comment: I was talking about the file synchronization between the host and the virtual machine. "Docker for Mac"!!!!! It sounds awesome, thanks for sharing.